# reboot and select proper boot device asus

Tags: windows-8, boot, asus-laptop

When I open my Asus K555L it shows this message "reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key" I tried pressing all keys nothing works it shows the same message , when I press f12 nothing happens , I have windows 8.1 I've looked everywhere and found no answer can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this problem is the list from which the BIOS chooses the boot device was altered, so it may be booting from something other than your hard drive.

A possible solution is to remove all connected USB devices and reboot. If this does not work, shut down the computer, press and HOLD F2 and power on. In the BIOS, you can change the boot order manually.

Finally, if the first option is your hard drive or Windows Boot Manager, but you still can't boot, your hard drive might be corrupt.